# How to design a class(course) schedule system with individual classes

Tags: database-design

I need to design a class system that has individual lesson time (say, 4 of them for each class), so I cannot simply have `start_time` and `end_time` like a normal university class. This is due to lessons being 1 on 1 so students have more freedom on changing the time.

I'm thinking of a OneToMany relationship between `Lesson` and `LessonTime` with `LessonTime` being just datetime, but does that make sense to create a table just for datetime?

Or should they be a ManyToMany? Since another `Lesson` can have the same `LessonTime`

What would be a better or more efficient idea?

Comment: If the lessons will be 1-on-1, then you need a separate instance of the Lesson for each student - but this instance will still have a start and end, the only special thing will be that different students will have different start times and end times - so a quick learner will take the Lesson in 25 minutes while a fool will need 95 minutes for the same Lesson. In both cases your Lesson instances will need at least 4 columns - lesson_id, student_id, lesson_start, lesson_end.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I think you misunderstood my description. Say this is a piano lesson and a student can request 4 classes within a month. These are, say, 1/1 1pm, 1/9 2:10pm, 1/13 3:20pm, 1/28 4:30pm. So the start_time and end_time is not very useful here. they don't store much info except maybe the month (which I can do in just one column)

Comment: It seems that my naming has confused you. What I meant was to use 2 timestamp values which also include the time zone. So you will know the date, time (with milliseconds precision) and the timezone when the lesson started and the same information about when the lesson is expected to finish. Using 2 TIMESTAMP columns (or 1 `tstzrange` column) is much better for searching and indexing than 3 columns - DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME. It will allow you to add exclusion constraint so that the same student can not participate several lessons at the same time.